# How to import font awesome to my react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome

I want to import font awesome to my react project. so how do I do it? I do it using below imports, but it doesn't work. I used the npm and it imported to my project. But I can't get the font awesome using this import. Help me!

```
npm install --save react-fontawesome
```

Then I write as below.

```
return (
  <FontAwesome
    className='super-crazy-colors'
    name='rocket'
    size='2x'
    spin
    style={{ textShadow: '0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)' }}
  />
```

I refer to this link:

[Font awesome and react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fontawesome)

Comment: Link is broken. You referred to https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fontawesome#usage?

Comment: Did you import the CSS from the CDN. Please check the documentation of the react-fontawesome. `Note: This component does not include any of the Font Awesome CSS or fonts, so you'll need to make sure to include those on your end somehow, either by adding them to your build process or linking to CDN versions.`

Comment: yeh..I try it but it doesn't work.so that is the problem but i found a way for this..too long method

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` in your `index.html`, or else something like `import node_modules/blah/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css;` in your `index.js` file.

Comment: .bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> is not worked for me..font awesome icons didn't work..

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. What error do you get?

Comment: There are no errors..But it doesn't work when i include above link.